# Display Limited value of Measurement for Salesman

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssas, mdx

Goal:
Make a limition of the measurement "Internet Sales Amount" value to 14545058,5455 without using any dimension table. The sales man is not allowed to view the whole value of mesurement "Internet Sales Amount". Only allowed to view limited of data in "Internet Sales Amount".

Problem:
I have problem to make a limitation of the measurement "Internet Sales Amount" that shall be access for Excel and SSRS.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Case
>
> ```
>     When [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] > ([Customer].[Gender].&[M], [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
>         Then "NA-gender"
>
>     When [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] > ([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008], [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
>         Then "NA-Calender"
>
>     When [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] < ([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008], [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
>         Then "NA-Calender2"
>
>     Else [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] End
> ```